# How to say watching a movie changes your feelings?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

I want to say if you watch this movie "It makes you happy" or "It makes you be happy". Which one is better ? I don't want to use this part "if you watch this movie".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either one of these:

> It makes you happy.

or:

> It makes you feel happy.

I think "feel happy" sounds more natural than "be happy." We often use "feel «*emotion*»" when talking about how our feelings might sway because of music we hear, art we see, or programs we watch.

> This song makes me feel sad.
>   That painting makes me feel calm.
>   That comedy helps me feel silly.

The *feel* isn't necessary, but I think it sounds better than "be «*emotion*»" in most contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a movie that your friend has seen before?

If it's a movie that they've seen before and you know it makes them happy, feel free to remark:

> This movie makes you happy.
>
> You really enjoy this movie, don't you?

But if it's a movie they haven't seen before and you are merely stating what effect you think it'll have on them, I'd recommend a future construction:

> It'll make you happy.
>
> This is going to make you happy.
>
> You'll enjoy this.
>
> You'll love this.

Alternatively, if you are using "you" as an impersonal pronoun and your intended meaning is that the movie "makes people (in general) happy", then I'd say:

> This movie tends to make people happy.
>
> This is a very enjoyable movie.
>
> It's a feel-good movie.